# Using before blocks result in failing Rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm having some issues using the before block in Rspec. In the code below, I am unable to remove the `allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane)` lines. In the second chunk of code, I have the same issue, but with `allow(plane).to receive(:take_off_plane)`. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

```
describe '#land' do
    context 'when not stormy' do
      before :each do
        allow(airport.weather).to receive(:stormy_weather?).and_return(false)
        allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane)
      end
      it 'should tell the plane to land' do
        plane = double(:plane, airborne: true)
        allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane) # can't put this into before block?
        expect(airport).to receive(:land)
        airport.land(plane)
      end

      it 'should have plane in the Airport' do
        plane = double(:plane, airborne: true)
        allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane)
        airport.land(plane)
        expect(airport.planes_in_airport).to include plane
      end

      it 'should raise error when trying to land a landed plane' do
        plane = double(:plane, airborne: false)
        message = "This plane is already landed."
        expect{ airport.land(plane) }.to raise_error message
      end

      context 'when full' do
        it 'should raise an error' do
          plane = double(:plane, airborne: true)
          allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane)
          airport.capacity.times {airport.land(plane)}
          message = "Sorry. Airport full. Go away."
          expect{airport.land(plane)}.to raise_error message
        end
      end
    end
```

--

```
describe '#take_off' do
    context 'when not stormy'
    before do
      allow(airport.weather).to receive(:stormy_weather?).and_return(false)
      allow(plane).to receive(:take_off_plane)
    end
    it 'should remove plane from Airport' do
      plane = double(:plane, airborne: false)
      allow(plane).to receive(:take_off_plane) # can't delete this
      airport.planes_in_airport.push(plane)
      airport.take_off(plane)
      expect(airport.planes_in_airport).not_to include(plane)
    end
  end
```

Comment: It looks like you are not defining `plane` until the `it` block, so I wouldn't expect `allow(plane)` to work in the `before` block. What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the error message, if any?

Comment: Apologies for leaving out the error message. I get this error when commenting out 'should have plane in airport', for example:

`1) Airport#land when not stormy should have plane in the Airport
     Failure/Error: airport.land(plane)
       Double :plane received unexpected message :land_plane with (no args)`

Comment: Also, at the top of my spec file, I have this, which should define plane before the block right?:

`require 'airport'
describe Airport do

  subject(:airport) { described_class.new }
  let(:plane) {double :plane}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out the answer.

The challenge here is that I'm incorrectly creating new doubles within an expectation. For example:

```
 it 'should have plane in the Airport' do
        plane = double(:plane, airborne: true)
        allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane)
        airport.land(plane)
        expect(airport.planes_in_airport).to include plane
      end
```

In here, I shouldn't be using that `plane = double(:plane, airborne: true)` line. Or, for that matter, have that `allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane)` in there either. I should have both in the before block

I should have my before block looking like this:

```
before :each do
      allow(plane).to receive(:airborne).and_return(true)
      allow(plane).to receive(:land_plane)
      allow(airport.weather).to receive(:stormy_weather?).and_return(false)
    end
```

This removes the need for me to create those weird doubles in each expectation. It also means that the plane's airborne state is pre-defined. This occurs before I allow the plane double to receive the land_plane method. I was doing this the wrong way round before which meant that I was creating a double after telling it to accept the land_plane method, resulting in an unexpected message exception.

Thanks for looking at it and let me know if you have any further points!